# Replacing setData to add new Firebase Documents

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm new to Flutter and trying to change my code to add a new document within Firebase everytime addActivity is called. Right now my code is using the setData function which overwrites a single document, and I haven't been able to find a working solution tailored to my situation here.

I've attached a screenshot of how my Firebase database is set up, and the code i'm working with. If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated.

[Firebase Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WEIc.jpg)

And the code i'm working with:

```
Future addActivity(
    User myUser,
    User client,
    String title, {
    bool mineImage = true,
  }) async {
    print("Add Activity Called");
    var activityCollection =
        usersCollection.document(myUser.email).collection("activity");
    await activityCollection.document(client.username).setData({
      "title": title,
      // "time": DateTime.now().toString(),
      "time": getTime(),

      "imageUrl": (mineImage) ? myUser.imageUrl : client.imageUrl,

    });
    print("Added Activity");
  }

  String getTime() {
    DateTime time = DateTime.now();
    return(new DateFormat.yMMMd().add_jm().format(new DateTime.now()));
  }

  Future<DocumentSnapshot> docExists(
    String id,
  ) async {
    DocumentSnapshot document = await chatRoomsCollection.document(id).get();
    if (!document.exists) {
      print("Document $id does not exist");
      return null;
    } else {
      print("document $id exists");
      return document;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setData` replaces the whole document with the data which you have passed to that function.

`updateData` just updates the values which you have passed to that function and the data which is present in the document is untouched.

`add` will create a new document in your collection with a new unique document id.

You need to make changes to your addActivity function:

```
Future addActivity(
    User myUser,
    User client,
    String title, {
    bool mineImage = true,
  }) async {
    print("Add Activity Called");
    var activityCollection =
        usersCollection.document(myUser.email).collection("activity");
    await activityCollection.add({
      "title": title,
      // "time": DateTime.now().toString(),
      "time": getTime(),

      "imageUrl": (mineImage) ? myUser.imageUrl : client.imageUrl,

    });
    print("Added Activity");
  }
```

Comment: In this instance, updateData does the same thing as setData, updating the same document. Is there a function which adds an entirely new document, and leaves the current document untouched?

Comment: There is a function `add` same as `setData` and `updateData`, where you have pass data and it will create a new document. Use this [link](https://medium.com/@atul.sharma_94062/how-to-use-cloud-firestore-with-flutter-e6f9e8821b27) it will help you understand the basic function of firebase in flutter

Comment: ```add``` doesn't show as a valid function to replace ```updateData```. Can you help me?

Comment: You don't need to specify the document id.

Comment: I'm super new to Flutter, and i'm trying to fix someone else's code, so honestly I have no idea what to change in my code to not specify the Document ID. Would I just remove this whole section?

Comment: ```Future<DocumentSnapshot> docExists(
    String id,
  ) async {
    DocumentSnapshot document = await chatRoomsCollection.document(id).get();
    if (!document.exists) {
      print("Document $id does not exist");
      return null;
    } else {
      print("document $id exists");
      return document;
    }
  }```

Comment: No, that section is proper. I have made the necessary changes to your function `addActivity` and I have updated the answer.

Comment: See this [post](https://medium.com/@atul.sharma_94062/how-to-use-cloud-firestore-with-flutter-e6f9e8821b27), it will clear much of the doubt you have about firebase/firestore and flutter.

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked perfectly. I know the basics of connecting with Firebase, but seeing what you've changed makes complete sense. I couldn't figure that out for the life of me.